# Giving a range to Plot to plot multiple lines at the same time

Tags: plotting

I'd like to plot something like this:

[image]

Except that instead of manually specifying all the functions to be plotted, I specify a `range`. So for example I could feed the command `Range[0,6,2]` to get it to plot four lines on the same plot, i.e. $\mathrm{Sin}[0],\mathrm{Sin}[2x],\mathrm{Sin}[4x]$ and $\mathrm{Sin}[6x]$.

How can I do this? I tried `Plot[Sin[# x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ Range[1, 3]` which yields the desired three lines, but each in their own plot as opposed to one. Attempting to map twice with `Plot[#, {x, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ {Sin[# x] /@ Range[1, 3]}` yields no plot at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Plot[Sin[# x] & /@ Range[1, 3] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that [`Sin`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sin.html) is [`Listable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Listable.html)

```
Attributes[Sin]

(* {Listable, NumericFunction, Protected} *)

Plot[Evaluate@Sin[Range[3] x], {x, 0, 2 Pi},
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try `Show` to combine the plots

```
Show[Plot[Sin[# x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}] & /@ Range[1, 3] ]
```

or

```
Plot[Table[Sin[om x], {om, Range[1, 3] }] // Evaluate, {x, 0, 2 Pi}]
```